# Why do the rows with 0 disappear when I use having?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, having, coalesce

I have this tables:

```
create table series(
    serie       varchar(10),
    season          varchar(10),
    chapter     varchar(10),
    primary key ( serie, season, chapter)
);

insert into series values ('serie_1', 'season_1', 'Chap_1'),
                          ('serie_1', 'season_1', 'Chap_2'),              
              ('serie_1', 'season_2', 'Chap_1'),

              ('serie_2', 'season_1', 'Chap_1'),
              ('serie_2', 'season_2', 'Chap_1'),
              ('serie_2', 'season_2', 'Chap_2'),

              ('serie_3', 'season_1', 'Chap_1'),
              ('serie_3', 'season_2', 'Chap_1');

create table actua(
    idActor     varchar(10),
    serie       varchar(10),
    season      varchar(10),
    chapter     varchar(10),
    salary      numeric(6),
    foreign key ( serie, season, chapter) references series,
    primary key ( idActor, serie, season, chapter)
);

insert into actua values   ('A1', 'serie_1', 'season_1', 'Chap_1', 1000),
               ('A1', 'serie_1', 'season_1', 'Chap_2', 1000),
               ('A1', 'serie_1', 'season_2', 'Chap_1', 1000),                   
               ('A2', 'serie_1', 'season_2', 'Chap_1', 1000),       
               ('A3', 'serie_1', 'season_2', 'Chap_1', 1000),       

               ('A1', 'serie_2', 'season_1', 'Chap_1', 1000),
               ('A2', 'serie_2', 'season_1', 'Chap_1', 2000),       
               ('A2', 'serie_2', 'season_2', 'Chap_1', 2000),   
               
               ('A2', 'serie_3', 'season_1', 'Chap_1', 3000),
               ('A4', 'serie_3', 'season_1', 'Chap_1', 500)
               ;
```

I am trying to get the series and seasons in which the sum of the salaries is less than 4000, and if any season of a series has no associated actors, their sum will count as zero (serie_3, season_2)

My expected solution is:

```
|serie_1|season_1|2000|
|serie_1|season_2|3000|
|serie_2|season_1|3000|
|serie_2|season_2|2000|
|serie_3|season_1|3500|
|serie_3|season_2|   0|
```

First I tried to make a query to obtain the series, with their different seasons and the sum of the salaries in each one, besides substituting 0 in the row that has null:

```
select serie, season, coalesce(sum(salary), 0) 
from series natural left join actua group by serie, season order by serie, season
```

And I get my expected solution (because all the sums of the salaries are less than 4000)
Then I try to show the rows with salary less than 4000, which is actually all the rows; using the having clause:

```
select serie, season, coalesce(sum(salary), 0) 
from series natural left join actua group by serie, season having sum(salary) < 4000 order by serie, season
```

And the row in which I used the coalesce disappears, how can I show it when using the having?

Comment: Have you tried to use `sum(coalesce(salary,0))` instead of `coalesce(sum(salary), 0)`? `null < 4000` evaluates to `null`, eliminating it on the `having` filter. You could also use `having coalesce(sum(salary), 0) < 4000`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the sum of the NULL values that you get from the outer join is NULL, and NULL is not less than 4000:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL < 4000
            THEN 'NULL is less than 4000'
            ELSE 'it is not true that NULL is less than 4000'
       END;
                    case                    
════════════════════════════════════════════
 it is not true that NULL is less than 4000
```

Actually, if you compare NULL to anything, the result is always NULL ("unknown"), which is not true.

So you have to use `coalesce()` in the `HAVING` clause as well:

```
... HAVING coalesce(sum(salary), 0) < 4000
```

Comment: Couldn't you also do `HAVING SUM(salary) < 4000 IS TRUE`?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Yes, that's just as good, or even better, because it is more readable. There are many ways to skin the cat.